# Обновления страницы без её перезагрузки

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, mysql

У меня в браузерной игре есть чат. Как можно реализовать обновления чата без перезагрузки? Пробовал с помощью `jquery+ajax` - не получилось.

**UPD**

```
window.onload = function () {
    var loader = document.getElementById('chat_t');
    setInterval(function () {
        loader.load();
    }, 1000);
}
```

и

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#load').click(function () {
        $(this).load('/game.php?the=chat');
    })
});
```

Comment: > Пробовал с помощью jquery+ajax не
> получилось

Показываем код проб, и спрашиваем где косяк, что не так сделано, подскажите пожалуйста?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.get('chat.php?onlynew', function(data){
        $('#chat').append(data);
    });
}, 10000);
```

`onlynew` дает скрипту чата (`chat.php`) указание выводить только новые сообщения (как определить, какие новые - думайте сами), `#chat` - элемент, где выводятся сообщения, `data` - html-код сообщений (так проще подключить шаблонизатор).
Как вариант, результат можно возвращать в виде JSON и разбирать его на клиенте. Трафика будет жрать меньше.

Comment: setTimeout будет один раз проверять же. Загрузилась страница и за все ее существование она обновится один раз.

Answer (score 1):

Просто. Делаем скрипт, который проверяет наличие новых сообщений, если нет — пустой массив, если есть — массив с сообщениями. Дальше с помощью в JS мутим setInterval каждые N секунд с обращением к этому скрипту, соответственно выводим новые сообщения.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("window.location.reload()",10000);
</script>

Так?

Comment: @Riolu, ватафак мэн, я не писал такого!

    check.php: echo getNewMessages(); // Получаем список новых сообщений
    chat.php: setInterval("updateChat();", 10000) // Проверяем на наличие новых сообщения и заносим
    updateChat: function(){
      $.getJSON('check.php', function(data){ // i love jQ
        if(data.length > 0) $('#chat').append(data.text);
      });
    }

Примерно такое.

Comment: setInterval с ajax'ом - признак дурного тона.

Comment: @ling, да ну, расскажите ка тогда еще варианты.