# Сохранение выбранных значений в <select> и загрузка товара без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Помогите пожалуйста со скриптом.

Есть **4-5 `<select><option>`** форм, где находятся опции для фильтра товаров, очень хотелось бы, чтобы данная процедура происходила без перезагрузки страницы и сохраняла при этом выбранное значение в `<select>` для удобства пользователя.

Пробовали если не изменяет память, с помощью **'localStrorage, SessionStorage'** и напрямую сохранять значение и грузить запросом с базы данных данные, но ничего не вышло.

CMS - не использую, самописный шаблон.

Comment: Можно изменять URL без перезагрузки страницы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/137224/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B5%D1%91-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8?rq=1

Comment: Можно на сервере в сессии сохранять данные о фильтрации. http://www.softtime.ru/bookphp/gl8_1.php

Comment: В чем проблема в JS считать данные из localStrorage, SessionStorage и выполнить ajax запрос при загрузке страницы?

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но я не очень разбираюсь в этом к сожалению.

Comment: Мне просто нужен пример рабочий, чтобы разобраться что к чему

Comment: Может кто нибудь помочь?

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком общий

Comment: Не задавайте Вопросы со множеством возможных ответов или требующие одного, но очень длинного ответа.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: окей, просто обновление контента без перезагрузки страницы

Comment: Очевидно, что это можно сделать через JavaScript и AJAX.

Comment: потому и прошу у вас пример работы скрипта с <select><option> о обновление без перезагрузки страницы. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Создайте новый вопрос с указанием html разметки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve